# Make a choice which variable gets inserted inside array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two variables

```
$order_phone = $orders[$x]['phone'];
$order_mobile = $orders[$x]['mobile'];
```

Using a function out of the API i create a new array. Inside the array these variables will be set like this:

```
'telephone' => $order_phone . $order_mobile ,
```

Now I am getting into trouble when the length exceeds 20 characters. then I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'SendCloudApiException' with message 'telephone: "Ensure this field has no more than 20 characters."
```

Can I let the inserted variable be a choice? If 1 of the 2 is filled out let that variable be chosen or else always take the mobile number?

Below is the rest of the created array:

```
$createdParcel = $apiSend->parcels->create(

    array(
            'name'=> ($order_firstName . $order_middleName . $order_lastName),
            'company_name' => $order_companyName,
            'address' => ($order_addressBillingStreet . $order_addressBillingStreet2 . $order_addressBillingNumber . $order_addressBillingExtension),
            'city' => $order_addressBillingCity,
            'postal_code' => $order_addressBillingZipcode,
            'telephone' => $order_phone . $order_mobile ,
            'requestShipment' => false, // set to true when you want to request a shipment
            'email' => $order_email,
            'country' => strtoupper($order_addressBillingCountry['code']),
            'order_number' => $order_number
          )

);
```

Comment: Is it really useful to store two concatenated phone numbers?! If there is really no way to store two phone numbers then you have to decide which one should be prefered.

Comment: @maxhb well I need atleast 1 number, but i can't make the customer require to fill out only 1 number(not on my end at the moment). But the telephone in the array should have a value! So to make sure I have a value I would like it to be filled with atleast 1 telephone number. Plus for future reference, Would be handy to know how i could achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't understand the usefullness of concatenated phone numbers, but here we go.

```
// If both numbers together have a maximum legth of 20 chars: use them both
if(strlen($order_phone . $order_mobile) <= 20) {
  $phone = $order_phone . $order_mobile;
} else {
  if(!empty($order_mobile)) {
    // if a mobile number is given use that
    $phone = $order_mobile;
  } else {
    // Use phone number other wise
    $phone = $order_phone;
  }
}
// at this point $phone is a string <= 20 chars

$createdParcel = $apiSend->parcels->create(

    array(
            'name'=> ($order_firstName . $order_middleName . $order_lastName),
            'company_name' => $order_companyName,
            'address' => ($order_addressBillingStreet . $order_addressBillingStreet2 . $order_addressBillingNumber . $order_addressBillingExtension),
            'city' => $order_addressBillingCity,
            'postal_code' => $order_addressBillingZipcode,
            'telephone' => $phone , // Use phone number from above
            'requestShipment' => false, // set to true when you want to request a shipment
            'email' => $order_email,
            'country' => strtoupper($order_addressBillingCountry['code']),
            'order_number' => $order_number
          )

);
```

Comment: Thank you, It's not perse only now with telephone numbers but in general I did not know how to achieve this. Is it advised to avoid the concatenating of variables inside the array?

Comment: I would not concatenate values I can not separate afterwards.